# JPA Specification multiple join based on foreignkey

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa, specifications

I have following relationships between three objects

```
public class ProductEntity {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "productEntity",
               fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<ProductInfoEntity> productInfoEntityList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Column(name = "snippet")
    private String snippet;
}

public class ProductInfoEntity {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private ProductEntity productEntity;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "support_language_id")
    private SupportLanguageEntity supportLanguageEntity;
}


public class SupportLanguageEntity {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column("name")
    private String name;
}
```

And this is actual database design 
[image]

Then, I'd like to make a specification to query as followings:

select * from product_info
where product_id = 1
and support_language_id = 2;

I am also using annotation for the specification which means that I use ProductEntity_, ProductInfoEntity_ and so on.

Can you please give me a full working code for the specification for query mentioned above?

Thank you guys

Comment: Sorry, but SO is not a coding service. We won't write your code for you. But if you have tried something and can't get it to work, let us know what you tried, how it doesn't work and I'm sure someone will be able to give a hint how to proceed.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me, but I don't even have any idea of how to do this. I have searched through SO but couldn't find answers to my questions. Then, could you please give me any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use [Specification](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.0.M1/api/index.html?org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html) your `ProductInfoEntityRepository` have to extend [JpaSpecificationExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html)

```
@Repository
public interface ProductInfoEntityRepository 
    extends JpaRepository<ProductInfoEntity, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<ProductInfoEntity> {
}
```

As far as I understand you use `JPA` metamodel. So then

```
@Autowired    
ProductInfoEntityRepository repository;

public List<ProductInfoEntity> findProductInfoEntities(int productId, int languageId) {
    return repository.findAll((root, query, builder) -> {
        Predicate productPredicate = builder.equal(
                root.get(ProductInfoEntity_.productEntity).get(ProductEntity_.id), // or root.get("productEntity").get("id")
                productId); 

        Predicate languagePredicate = builder.equal(
                root.get(ProductInfoEntity_.supportLanguageEntity).get(SupportLanguageEntity_.id),  // or root.get("supportLanguageEntity").get("id")
                languageId);

        return builder.and(productPredicate, languagePredicate);
    });
}
```

If you want to make specifications reusable you should create utility class contains two static methods `productIdEquals(int)` and `languageIdEquals(int)`.

To combine them use [Specifications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.0.M1/api/index.html?org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specifications.html)(Spring Data JPA 1.*) or [Specification](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.0.M1/api/index.html?org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html)(since Spring Data JPA 2.0)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have got it working!!!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from product_info where product_id = 1 and support_language_id = 2;
```

Should work as written.  But the only thing useful will be `comment`.

Perhaps you want the rest of the info in all three tables?

```
SELECT  pi.comment,   -- list the columns you need
        p.snippet,
        sl.name
    FROM product AS p      -- table, plus convenient "alias"
    JOIN product_info AS pi  -- another table
        ON p.id = pi.product_info  -- explain how the tables are related
    JOIN support_language AS sl  -- and another
        ON pi.support_language_id = sl.id  -- how related
    WHERE  p.snippet = 'abc'   -- it is more likely that you will start here
    -- The query will figure out the rest.
```

From there, see if you can work out the obfuscation provided by JPA.